# Job of work distribution system

Tags: project-management, web

If you can think of a better title, then please update it; I am not too happy with this one.

The idea is that someone enters jobs of work which have to be done, and workers request work.

The workers will have smartphones, possibly tablets, so their part of the app should either be native Android ***and*** iOs (preferable), or browser based (acceptable).

The person who enters the jobs needs more screen real estate, so their part of the app will be either Windows or browser based.

Jobs get added to the queue; workers take them off; when they are done, they mark the job as done and take another.

That’s the bare minimum and I imagine that it will be commercial, rather than gratis.

To refine it, it would be nice if:

- There are different categories of workers, who match categories of jobs
- Information can be added to the jobs, such as:

  - Location
  - Contact person
  - Notes
  - History e.g for repairs, details of previous repairs
  - Images
  - Documents (e.g manuals/user guides)
  - Estimated time to completion

It would also be nice if report can be generated, with colo(u)red charts and reports for management.

Of course, it also needs some admin, not just to add CRUD (Create/Read/Update/Delete)  jobs,  but worked too.

If this sounds vague, it is because I am looking for a generic solution which can be used in many fields.

Hit me with the most full-featured solution you know of, and feel free to suggest useful features (e.g mapping).

Comment: Hi - Will Task Management Systems like Trac, Trello etc. also work for this? If so, some already have mobile app. Can then change title to something like  "Generic Task Management System with Web/Mobile app" and enter full answer.

Comment: Do you have URLs? Trac seems to be many things

Comment: Trac: https://trac.edgewall.org/  https://trello.com

Comment: A very interesting idea  - I normally use issue management systems like this for bug reporting. But, if view a "bug" as "this job needs to be done", I can see how it might work. Alas, issue shave to be assigned to a user, not a group of them. Also, it's not so easy (but not impossible) to track history of related issues and hours spent per worker, but I will certainly give this some serious thought. Thanks

Comment: Hi - curious... Did you find something? Or did you build a solution?

Comment: The potential customer lost interest, so I did too :-)  IMO, while this sounds like there might be a generic solution, it is likely to be mediocre, and something bespoke would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Entering an Answer, as comments getting too long.

The idea is to use your preferred Task Management System for managing the work. Bug trackers can be used too, assuming it is flexible enough to change labelling from "Bug" to "Job to be done". Hence the reason I suggested looking at [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org), [Trello](http://trello.com), etc. Some of the more modern ones have Mobile apps too.

I have done something similar in past, but without a mobile app though, using drupal's [CaseTracker](https://www.drupal.org/project/casetracker).

If you need to allocate to a group of users, the quick way I got around this was to have a mailing list for the group of users. So each member gets notification. The list was set up as a dummy user.

For related issues, you can have tags for linking issues or have a field "Related Issues" which brings up IDs of all jobs/issues, which user selects if necessary.

You can then add other fields as necessary e.g. Location, Contact Person, Document, Images etc.

Different categories of workers can be achieved via Roles specific to your Job categories. When you set up a user, you add them to one or more roles.

Comment: Almost perfect, except for emailing users when new jobs are added. I want them to kanban - finish one task & take another from th elist

Comment: With what I did in past, emailing users when new jobs are added was achieved by notification for the content type "Job". In my case, only the role that approve jobs get notified. But you can send email to all or selected users if required.

Comment: I am beginning to think that I will develop my own

Comment: Yes, no matter what solution you pick, you will still need some custom coding for specific functionality. Same in my case too...

Comment: Oh, well. If I make it generic enough, maybe I can sell it :-)

Comment: Before you start, also look at other project management ones for ideas e.g. https://kanboard.org/ and its plugins; https://www.redmine.org/  https://wekan.github.io/  https://taskboard.matthewross.me/