# Company process management software

Tags: web-apps

I am looking for software for creating processes and managing them in the company - I can explain the case example :)

The system should be able to define individual steps of the entire process along with the identification of the person who will perform them and the time of implementation.

- The customer places an order for advertising t-shirts

  1. We start the process - a new T-shirt order
  2. The task is assigned to the graphic designer - prepare the visualization - deadline of 24 hours
  3. person at the secretary's office receives the task - prepare a pro-form - deadline - 6h

Graphic designer - approves the visualization, the person from the secretariat seeing the ready visualization sends it to the client in a pro-form.

The secretariat receives a new task - reminder whether the client has approved the visualization - deadline - 72h (after exceeding the deadline reminder for the secretariat - contact the client no response from him)
We get the approval of the client's graphic design - the secretary means the task done
Another task for accounting - has the transfer been pro-forma? - Accounting confirms
Task for printers - we realize orders for t-shirts - 72h
....
And so on :) Of course, this is just an example of part of one process - but I wanted to outline the functionality of the application.
Do any of you know of an application that could help us? Preferably open-source but it is not a requirement :) May be paid per-user in reasonable money.

Comment: Sounds like you need something for task/project management? If not, please clarify question further. Also see my previous answer to a related question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/62150/job-of-work-distribution-system/62684#62684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you could use [Processmaker](https://www.processmaker.com/). You can create the processes via web interface, and once created you can also track the processes in your company. 
There's an open source community version, and even a VM on
[Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/processmaker)